# Can we omit past participle?

Tags: grammar

I think it is okay to combine these two sentences like this:

> We stood on a bridge. The bridge was built in 2000.
>
> We stood on the bridge **built in 2000.**

Is it okay?

Also is it okay to omit past participle  "**built**" like this?

> We stood on the bridge **in 2000.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  If you omit *built*, then the meaning of the sentence changes:

> We stood on the bridge [which was] built in [the year] 2000.

This means that the bridge was built in the year 2000.

> We stood on the bridge in [the year] 2000.

This means you stood there at some point in the year 2000.  It was built either the same year or earlier.

Comment: Thanks snailboat. How about ...We stood on a bridge. The bridge was built over the long river. Can I omit a past particile in this case?  Is it okay to write " We stood on the bridge over the long river."?

Comment: @nkm Yes, but "built" isn't implied in the latter.  Instead, it means "the bridge [that was] over the long river".

Comment: Also worth noting that in the OP's original example of "We stood on the bridge built in 2000" it implies that there is only 1 bridge built in 2000 (at least among the bridges that, from context, the reader knows they can be choosing from.) In the absence of context, "We stood on a bridge [that was] built in 2000" is far preferable. cc @nkm

Comment: @WendiKidd Oh, that's a good point.  The combined version of the original two sentences should use ***a***, not ***the***.  (I overlooked this point while writing my answer.)